# Finding the smallest value n from which the difference between the sum of an infinite series and a partial sum is less than 0,001

Tags: series-expansion

Basically I was told that this "the [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) function generally doesn't handle infinite series very well.

Choose some values of n and see how large the error is, then see if you can find a value of $n$ where the error is close to 0.001". The series is $1/k!$.

I am confused about how I can use the solve function to find an error at all. I tried this

```
Solve[Sum[1/k!, {k, 1, ∞}] == -1 + E, k]
```

It doesn't even give me an error.

Comment: This tells you that `n` can be taken as 6 or 7: `In[535]:= n /. FindRoot[Sum[1/k!, {k, n, Infinity}] == 1/1000, {n, 10}]

Out[535]= 6.25056872869`

Comment: `Sum[1/k!, {k, 1, Infinity}] == -1 + E` evaluates to `True` so the `Solve` correctly states that any value of `k` works. Look at `Solve[Sum[1/k!, {k, 1, \[Infinity]}] == -1 + E, k] // Trace`

Answer (score 1):

You ask for an error, so I presume you want to compare *partial sums* with the (known) value of the infinite sum. So you could do things like the following:

```
N[Sum[1/k!,{k,1,n}]-(E-1)]/.n->5

Table[{n, N[Sum[1/k!, {k, 1, n}] - (E - 1)]}, {n, 10}] // TableForm

ListLinePlot[Table[Sum[1/k!, {k, 1, n}] - (E - 1), {n, 10}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Pick an upper bound for `n`, 10, 20, 100 whatever you feel is big enough. Then put bounds on `n` and `Solve` over the `Integers`:

```
Min[n /. Solve[
   Abs[Sum[1/k!, {k, 1, n}] - (-1 + E)] < 1/1000 && 0 < n < 100, n, 
   Integers]]

(*  6  *)
```